# TeXnicCenter - makeindex does not generate acronyms and glossary at ones

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, texniccenter

I am currently working on my master thesis and have to use MiKTeX in combination with TeXnicCenter for writing. I ran across a problem with `makeindex`.

In my Tex Files I use the `glossary` package. With this I create glossary entries and acronyms. TeXnicCenter allows me to insert one `makeindex` command. This is currently

```
"%tm".glo -t "%tm".glg -s "%tm".ist -o "%tm".gls
```

With this command I do not get what I exactly want. I get this via running the windows commands:

```
makeindex Masterarbeit.glo -s Masterarbeit.ist -t Masterarbeit.glg -o Masterarbeit.gls
makeindex -s Masterarbeit.ist -t Masterarbeit.alg -o Masterarbeit.acr Masterarbeit.acn
```

Is it possible to merge this into one and insert it into TeXnicCenter?

I noticed, that `makeindex` has to be executed before the pdf generation. How to trigger this? (So that new acronyms and glossary entries will be used then)

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is the message, when I do not run my windows commands before pdf creation:

> pdfTex warning (dest): name{glo:ABC} has been referenced but does not
>   exist, replaces by a fixed one

Comment: Do you actually mean the `glossary` package (which has been obsolete for nearly 10 years) or did you mean to write the `glossaries` package?

Answer (score 2):

The right order of runs to get your pdf file including glossary and acronyms is:

1. `pdflatex Masterarbeit.tex` (This first run creates the files you need for the creation of glossary and acronyms)
2. `makeindex` (to make the glossary and the second `makeindex` to create the acronyms (later we use a batch to do both runs with one call))
3. `pdflatex` (to include TOC, glossary and acronyms)
4. `pdflatex` (to get correct page numbers at last)

I think the quickest way is to create a Windows batch file `mwe.bat` with two lines, containing both commands you need to run `makeindex` two times:

```
makeindex Masterarbeit.glo -s Masterarbeit.ist -t Masterarbeit.glg -o Masterarbeit.gls
makeindex -s Masterarbeit.ist -t Masterarbeit.alg -o Masterarbeit.acr Masterarbeit.acn
```

Put the batch file into the same directory where you have your `tex` code.

I could be that you have to add the relevant pathes, you will see when you try it.

In TeXnicCenter you have predefined output profiles, but you can define new ones by your own. Go in TeXnicCenter menu to `Build` --> `Define Output profiles` and select the profile you use to compile.  Click `Copy` and type in a new name for the new copied profile, for example `mwe-makeindex`.

Check `(La)TeX` and click on the last box to uncheck (do not use makeindex in this profile).

Now click on `post processor`, click on `new` (find the symbol for a directory)  and type a post processor name `glossary`. Add to `executables` the name of your batch file `mwe.bat` (add the path if needed).  To close the window click on the OK button.

With this construction you can use the new output profile to compile your `tex` code and to use afterwards automaticly by TeXnicCenter the batch file `mwe.bat` to run both `makeindex` commands you need.

After compiling first, you get all files you need for `makeindex`. Then the batch is called to run both commands (thats the reason I used the **post** processor!).

The next compile run can work with both results of both `makeindex` commands.

I have only the german version of TeXnicCenter, but if you want I can include screenshots if the advice above is not clear.